# Return top three transaction on the basis of amount?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have a table `transaction(id, quantity, rate, stock_code, user_code)`, and I want to generate the top three transactions on the basis of their amount in descending order. `Amount = quantity * rate`

Is there a way to generate using only sql?

Comment: Yes it could be done with sql but you need to provide some sample data and expected output.

Comment: You could use [`LIMIT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#idm140653100375472) - `SELECT * FROM transaction ORDER BY quantity * rate DESC LIMIT 3;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible:

```
SELECT id, quantity * rate as amount, stock_code, user_code 
FROM transaction
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 3;
```